# Timeout error when connect to remote HBase

Tags: hbase

When I connecting to a remote HBase cluster I see a lot of this messages:

`17/07/26 03:17:21 INFO RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=12, retries=31, started=158602 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 10000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=ip-172-22-123-54.us-west-2.compute.i`

and then an exception:

    `at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:4422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:4414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.getClusterStatus(HBaseAdmin.java:2972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.RegionSizeCalculator.init(RegionSizeCalculator.java:100)`

What is the root cause of these issue?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the hbase has already started .close the firewall.  Check whether time synchronization  .

use the right hbase port
 The old version use port `60000`
and the new version use port `16010` to connect